# Editing font size of navigation bar links in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to change the font size of the navigation bar on my company's website: http://bicycle.ns.ca/

I've tried to edit the CSS through the theme that is currently installed but no changes occur still.

I also dived into the themes style.css file and tried various things like:

```
a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit properties of top menu tag.. try this!

```
 .top-menu a 
{
  color: #6b6b6b;
  font-size: 25px; <!–– Try Editing Here ––>
  line-height: 12px;
  display: block;
  }
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. But after increasing the size of the menu items the navbar moves down the page, and ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font site of the menu items in menu by adding the following CSS property for menu links

```
.top-menu a{
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```